# use variable name in mutate_if predicate

Tags: r, dplyr, nse

I can use the `vars()` wrapper inside `mutate_at` to perform a mutation on variables whose names are in a character vector:

```r
library(tidyverse)

varnames <- c("mpg", "am")

mtcars.mod <- mtcars %>%
  mutate_at(vars(varnames),
            funs(as.factor(.)))

is.factor(mtcars.mod$mpg)
#> [1] TRUE
```

But what if I want to add a predicate/condition on those variables, like I could do with `mutate_if`? In other words, I want to perform a mutation on variables which (1) are included in `varnames` and (2) satisfy a predicate, such as `!is.factor()`

My attempt, which fails:

```r
mtcars.mod <- mtcars %>%
  mutate_if(~ (names(.) %in% varnames & !is.factor(.)),
            funs(as.factor(.)))
#> Error in selected[[i]] <- .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): replacement has length zero
```

I suspect that `names(.)` might be returning NULL here.

Comment: this works, `mtcars.mod <-  mtcars %>%
  mutate_if((names(.) %in% varnames & !is.factor(.)),
            funs(as.factor(.)))` , `is.factor(mtcars.mod$mpg) #[1] TRUE`

Comment: Hmm yeah, it looks like it does. It's not clear to me when the `~` is required. For example, this fails but works if `~` is added: `mtcars.mod <- mtcars %>% mutate_if((is.numeric(.) & !is.factor(.)), funs(as.factor(.)))`